# I Dont Know What's Wrong With My Query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *,
(SELECT * 
 FROM regions WHERE regions.RID=registration.REGION) as region_out 
FROm registration
```

> 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Everything... use inner join

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT r1.*, r2.*
FROM registration r1,
INNER JOIN regions r2 ON ( r2.RID=r1.REGION )
```

Comment: Thanks men :D im trying to use nested select but this one helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries can only return a single value, so you can't do `SELECT *`. That's what the error message is telling you. You can only select a single column or value.

Answer (score 0):

better you write:

```
SELECT registration.*, regions.* 
FROM regions 
join registration on regions.RID=registration.REGION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM registration
LEFT JOIN regions ON (regions.RID=registration.REGION);
```